# How to disable Chrome throttling background tab in-app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I'm running an Angular application that uses Deepstream for communication. Deepstream uses SetIntervals which gets delayed when the application's `document.hidden` is `true` which means if it's either minimized or the tab is in the background (not the currently selected tab)

I tried setting chrome flags such as "Throttle expensive background timers" and "enable resource load throttling" but the issue where communications gets delayed persist.

Lastly, I tried making the application play constant audio file in a loop which fixes the issue, but that's hardly a fix but more of a cheat which will eventually get patched.

Does anyone have a preferably in-app (code) solution for this? changing more flags is okay but I'd actually rather avoid it for the client's sake.

Comment: Use WebSocket or SSE. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/#state-polling